# echo >> Gives an Error Saying the File Doesn't Exist

Tags: bash, shell

According to research, echo >> should create the file if it doesn't exist. (EDIT!! echoing to a file in the base terminal works. For some reason, it doesn't work in the .sh.) It works on the integrated "git bash" terminal, but not in MSYS2 MINGW. And one of my friends said that it gave an error in Fedora as well. My code is trying to detect if the cloned repo is the right version, and it will `git pull origin main` if it is outdated. Here is the code.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
NC='\033[0m' #Reset text color.
P='\033[0;35m' #Purple
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')") #get the base directory of start.sh
cd $basedir
ver=$(sed '1!d' $(dirname $(pwd))/.version) #get local version
if ! [ -f .var/asked ]; then #this is in place so it only asks the below question once, ever.
  if ! [ -f .var/vc ]; then #I don't know why this is here anymore
    echo "Would you like ScratchLang to check its version every time you start it? [Y/N]"
    read -sn 1 ff
    if [ h$ff == hy ] || [ h$ff == hY ]; then
      echo >>.var/vc "Don't remove this file please." #when start.sh detects this file, it will check for a new version.
    fi
    echo >>.var/asked "Don't remove."
  fi
fi
if [ -f .var/vc ]; then
  if ! [ h$1 == hnope ]; then
    echo "Checking version..."
    if [ -f .version ]; then
      rm .version
    fi
    wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0K9090/ScratchLang/main/.version #get the .version file from github
    utd=1
    if ! [ "$ver" == "$(sed '1!d' .version)" ]; then #if local version doesn't match .version from github, then set utd to 0
      utd=0
    fi
    if [ $utd == 0 ]; then #if utd = 0 then update
      echo "Your version of ScratchLang ($ver) is outdated. The current version is $(sed '1!d' .version). Would you like to update? [Y/N]"
      read -sn 1 hh
      if [ h$hh == hy ] || [ h$hh == hY ]; then
        git pull origin main
      fi
      exit
    fi
    rm .version
  fi
fi
```

Comment: My first thought (without reading through your script): Does the user running this have permission to create the file in that location?

Comment: Fedora is a Linux distribution, not a shell. The POSIX standard specifies that `>>` should create the target if it doesn't exist, but not all shells are POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes, the user has permission.

Comment: @chepner Then how do I create a file that will work for all shells?

Comment: You don't. That's why things like the POSIX standard exists: so that you can target the *standard*, and it's the responsibility of the user to execute the script with a compliant shell.

Comment: @chepner So if I'm understanding correctly, I make some code for one shell, then in another shell version I edit the code to fit the shell that it is being used in?

Comment: @chepner I don't know of any shell where `>>` won't create the file, why are you bringing up this possibility?

Comment: @chepner I made an edit that may be of interest.

Comment: My guess is that the `.env` directory doesn't exist. `>>` will create files, but it won't create directories.

Comment: You don't need to be compatible with all shells. If you have `#!/bin/bash` then you only have to be bash-compatible or you run the script with `bash scriptname` you only have to be compatible with `bash`. There are some small differences between bash versions, but nothing that I think would affect `>>`.

Comment: @Barmar I'll try adding a file extension.

Comment: Shell scripts should not have filename extensions (except when they're libraries rather than executables, but that isn't the case here). The `#!/bin/bash` shebang (and appropriate file permissions) is all you need.

Comment: (see the essay at https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ describing why putting extensions on your scripts is a Bad Idea)

Comment: ...it's more likely than anything else that you just don't have a `.var` directory under your script's current working directory. Add `mkdir -p -- .var || exit` before the first place where you do a redirection to `.var/...anything...`.

Comment: BTW, your script does have some other bugs -- run it through http://shellcheck.net/ for a list -- but for the one the title refers to, the `mkdir` specified above should suffice.

Comment: (also, note that `.var` is relative to the working directory from which you call the script, which is *not* the same as the directory the script is located in).

Comment: (also, don't use `$(pwd)`; it's a slower, less-efficient, and generally _worse_ way to retrieve the same value you'd otherwise get from `$PWD`).

Comment: ls doesn't output the directory, however the .var dir is in the same location as start.sh. I'll remove the dot to see if that works

Comment: ok why does that work